# Collections.sort() on Query list throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Query result sets are not modifiable

Tags: java, sorting, jdo, datanucleus, unsupportedoperation

I have this JDO service returning a `List<Order>`:

```
public List<Order> getOnGoingOrders() {

        List<Order> orderList = null;
        JDOPersistenceManager pm = (JDOPersistenceManager) persistenceManager.getPM();

        try {

            Query<Order> q = pm.newQuery(Order.class);

            q.setFilter("orderStatus != 'COMPLETED' && orderStatus != 'CANCELLED'");
            q.setOrdering("orderPlacedTime desc");

            orderList = (List<Order>) q.execute();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return orderList;
    }
```

When the front end calls `Collections#sort()` on it, I get the below exception:

```
 com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Query result sets are not modifiable
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractQueryResultIterator.set(AbstractQueryResultIterator.java:86)
    at java.util.List.sort(List.java:482)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.singleSort(SortFeature.java:148)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.encode(SortFeature.java:106)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:80)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:582)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:827)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITabPanel.visitTree(UITabPanel.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:322)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
    at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext.processPartial(OmniPartialViewContext.java:139)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:432)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler.renderView(NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler.java:93)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.listener.request.DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.render(DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.java:111)
    at javax.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleWrapper.render(LifecycleWrapper.java:92)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.listener.request.JsfClientWindowAwareLifecycleWrapper.render(JsfClientWindowAwareLifecycleWrapper.java:160)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: The error message TELLS you the problem. You get an implementation of List back from the persistence provider and it is their custom type and does not support changing. So put the results in your own List (which does support changing)! Basic java. PS I would have thought one of the reasons for putting the "ORDER BY" would be to order the elements of the List so why you want to order them again later I've no idea

Comment: I have the need to reorder because i use DN 2.1, which has a BUG handling ordered LISTS (cannot persist an ordered collection after changing the ORDER COLUMN, so i cannot define the ORDERING meta-data for these kind of list-fields).

Comment: In my experience all bugs I had in old versions of software are fixed in later versions, and there seem to be many many versions after DN2.1

Comment: Here's an idea, why don't you ACCEPT an answer

Comment: i did not found any way to fix this issue ???

Comment: If you "did not found any way" then why not POST that against the ANSWERS you have been given and then those people can attempt to find out from you WHAT HAPPENED when you did what they asked

Answer (score 4):

I don't know Persistance Manager you are using (JDO), but it seems that the result list returned by the query is not modifiable (you can read about that in JDO documentation probably).

Try to create a new List, do an addAll() with the query results, and use that List.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a Primefaces / JSF issue. The sort function is too trivial for that. Your xhtml looks fine on the first sight.

Try to initialize the list as an empty list like

`private ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<order>()`

..before load the data. So you can ensure that there is never 'a null list'.
Moreover, have you checked if the data have been loaded properly? Otherwise, try to retrieve the data by `q.getResultList()`. In my cases, I have always used this method and there weren't any problems.
Another tip: Try to copy your retrieved list from DB to an extra return list (like a safe copy) with `addAll()` and return that one.